# Invertibility of $BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having trouble with the following question which may seem simple but to me it's not

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{5 \times 7}, B\in \mathbb{R}^{7 \times 5}$.
> Prove that $BA$ is not invertible.

---

I thought maybe use the relation to the solution sets of $Ax=0$ which is infinite, hence $A$ isn't invertible. But I don't know where to head from here?

---

By the way, I'm looking for a counterexample that shows $AB$ doesn't have to be non-invertible.
Thanks in advance to all who bother to reply!

Comment: If (BA)C = I then B(AC) = I, showing that B, thought of as a linear transformation from a 7 dimensional space to a 5 dimensional space, is invertible. Can you show that any linear transformation form R^7 to R^5 isn't 1-1?

Comment: Considering we didn't study L.Ts yet, no :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is a $5 \times 7$ matrix, so its null space must have dimension at least $2$.  If $Ax = 0$ then $BAx = 0$.  So the null space of $BA$ has dimension at least $2$, and $BA$ is not invertible.

Comment: I don't think so. The null space of a $7\times 5$ matrix can well be $\{0\}$. It's the null space of $A$ that has dimension at least $2$ and your argument proves that $BA$ is not invertible.

Comment: Oops, got $A$ and $B$ mixed up somehow.  Edited.

Answer (score 5):

$BA$ is a $7 \times 7$ matrix, so it needs to be rank 7 to be invertible, But, since $\mbox{rank} (BA) \leq \min(\mbox{rank}(A),\mbox{rank}(B)) \leq 5$ (since $A,B$ have one dimension as $5$) it cannot be invertible.

$AB$ on the other hand can be invertible (for example, generate two matrices with i.i.d. standard normal entries for $A,B$ and then multiply them together and you'll probably get an invertible matrix if you try it a few times).

Comment: We didn't study yet about ranks of matrices (nor this theorem is something that we can use in the future, whose proof is pretty complicated), so is there a different way of solving this?
P.S what's i.i.d?

Comment: i.i.d. means independent and identically distributed. In Matlab, "A=randn(5,7);B=randn(7,5); sprintf('Rank A*B: %i Rank B*A: %i',rank(A*B),rank(B*A))". printing A*B and B*A will give you the matrices; if rank(A*B) = 5 then it is invertible (which will probably happen). If rank(B*A) = 7 (which is impossible) it would be invertible. As for use in the future, I'd be surprised if you did linear algebra with never encountering rank.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $BA$ cannot be invertible: there exists a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^7$ such that $Ax=0$ and $x\ne0$, because the homogeneous linear system $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions. Then $BAx=0$, which can't happen for an invertible matrix.

However, the matrix $AB$ *can* be invertible. Just to make a simple example,
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
is invertible. Now it's easy to extend this to the required size:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$