# If A is 5 * 7 and B is 7 * 5 Prove that BA is singular.

Tags: matrices

I need to show that if $ A $ and $ B $  are $ 5 \times 7 $ and $ 7 \times 5 $ matrices respectively, then the matrix $ BA $ is singular. Is that correct for $ AB $ as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $A$ has dimension $5 \times 7$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870747/invertibility-of-ba/1870775#1870775
I guess we both study in the Open University?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What size is $BA$? What can we say about its rank?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $ A $ is a linear map $ K^7 \to K^5 $ for some field $ K $. Can it be injective?